# Variance of estimate variances

Tags: statistics, variance

Assuming the observed values $Y_i$ are Normal with mean $\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i$ and variance $1$, what are the
variances of the estimates
$${\sigma_1}^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}[(Y_{21} − Y_2)^2 + (Y_{22} − Y_2)^2]$$ and $\sigma^2=\sum({Z_i}^2/6)$?

n=2 which is why 1/(n-1) was not included.

I am not really sure what is being asked.  The variance is $E(x^2) - [E(x)]^2$
so is it the $E(\sigma^2) - [E(\sigma)]^2$?  that seems to easy but it is the only thing I have thought of.
does it have to do with the distributions?  normal vs Chi^2

$\sigma^2 = 
(\sigma_1^2+
\sigma_2^2+
\sigma_3^2$)/3

I am not sure of anything else.  Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Comment: It's more likely asking about $E[(\sigma^2)^2]-E[\sigma^2]^2=E[(\sigma^2-E(\sigma^2))^2]$.

Comment: you are correct, that is what I meant to type.  I am supposed to calculate the variance of sigma^2 1 and 2.  The variables should follow a chi-squared distribution and the variance of a chi-squared distribution is 2*df.

Comment: thank you Laufen ~ I was struggling with the formatting!